# X:Name in workflow foundation 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

What is the alternative of x:name in workflow foundation 4.0.

I was working on WWF3.5 and I used x:name to identify each activity, now in WWF4.0 it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WF4 each activity had an ID when executing but you cannot assign that yourself. If you need something you can assign all you can do is use the DisplayName property.